# PowerPoint does not detect changes in Slide Library

Tags: office-integration

I have a problem with my Slide Library on Sharepoint 2010, whenever I use some slides from the "Slide Library" and save locally, when PowerPoint won't check for Updates. It all worked fine in the beginning.

I haven't played with any of the site setting, so i suspect there is a problem with PowerPoint or a random Windows 7 or PowerPoint service that our administrators have remove.

Any know what the problem can be? Thanks ^.^